# 502 bad gateway mvc core app on CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos, asp.net-core-mvc, bad-gateway

I made a website in MVC Core and tried to publish it to the web on a CentOS 7 VPS. It runs well, when I curl it it responds. Then i installed nginx and it showed the default page, when trying it from my computer. Then i changed nginx.conf to the below one and all i get is 502 bad gateway. In the nginx log i see only that a get request was received. Any ideas what should i check?

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
  #   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
     server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I tried apache and had the same problem. Then i found the solution, you have to set httpd_can_network_connect.

http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/

A didn't find the error message in the audit blog that the author was talking about but i tried his solution and it worked.

I have used centos for 4 days now and it's the second time i have to set a bit to solve a problem. These solutions are quite hidden in the web and most articles dealing with the area doesn't mention those so i lost a lot of time. So i share the opinion of the author about SELinux. Probably i will try another linux distribution.
What is also interesting that I followed the official microsoft tutorial "Set up a hosting environment for ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache, and deploy to it". The operating system that they use is CentOS too. And it doesn't mention this bit either.